# Postgresql will not listen unless restarted after every server restart

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, port, listen

I have a weird problem since I updated my Postgresql to 9.4 on my Ubuntu Server.
Every time I restart the server, I need to restart manually my PostgreSQL database as well in order that it listen the IP adresses that are in the postgresql.conf file:

[image]

Do you have any idea why it might happen?
Thanks!

Edit: The order of services on startup if that can help:

[image]

Comment: Aren't those IP addresses added too late? I mean - isn't postgresql starting before those IP addresses are assigned?

Comment: How can I check that? Normally it's part of the local network and their shouldn't be anything to do? Well it, has been working for 2 years perfectly with the same configuration before that.

Comment: Are those IPs assigned dynamically or over VPN? I would check order of services startup - http://serverfault.com/questions/472030/how-to-list-services-daemons-started-at-boot-and-check-their-loading-order

Comment: I edited the original post with the screenshot. IPs are dynamically assigned.

Comment: Server configuration is off-topic here, voted to move to Server Fault to maybe get better insights.